# sed fails as soon as I put \d or [0-9] in regex

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to match the '64' in :

```
state 0x0, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
```

and extract it.

I've tried

```
echo "$line" | sed -n -e 's/^.*keycode\s\([0-9]+\).*$/\1/p'
```

Which in my mind should work, but it does not.

After some more testing, the regex matches successfully, until I start introducing digits.

```
echo "$line" | sed -n -e 's/^.*keycode\s.*/test/p'
```

works fine, but

```
echo "$line" | sed -n -e 's/^.*keycode\s\d.*/test/p'
echo "$line" | sed -n -e 's/^.*keycode\s[0-9].*/test/p'
```

and related do not work, even though there is a digit right after the space.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Turns out I needed to use `[[:digit:]]`, \d isn't supported but [0-9] should be, any reason why that didn't work?

Comment: See: [In GNU sed, \d introduces a decimal character code of one to three digits in the range 0-255](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421095/removing-parts-of-a-string-that-contain-digit-with-sed-perl#comment3561607_3421095)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "work"? `[0-9]` does work for me in the sense that, as part of a regular expression, it allows me to extract the two digit number from the input string: `echo "state 0x0, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES," | sed -n -e 's/^.*keycode\s\([0-9]\{2\}\).*$/\1/p'` outputs `64`.

Comment: That's interesting, because it doesn't for me. Does "+" instead of "{2}" work for you?

Comment: Yes, if escaped: `\+`. What's your `sed --version`? `sed (GNU sed) 4.4` here.

Comment: `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`,. `apt-get install sed` claims it is the newest version. I just copied/pasted the command you wrote, and it succeeded. I must have done something wrong earlier, just not sure what. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one small mistake in your `sed` expression: the plus `+` character needs to be escaped.

```
echo "state 0x0, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES," | sed -n -e 's/^.*keycode\s\([0-9]\+\).*$/\1/p'
```

outputs `64` as expected. Those of us used to [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) syntax should pay attention to the differences when using other tools like `sed` or `awk`, each having a peculiar set of special characters, some of which need to be escaped, some not.

One example is `\d`, which stands for any digit in PCRE and has a different meaning in `sed`, as pointed out by Cyrus in his comment: `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` should be used instead.

`perl -e` is generally as capable as `sed` and `awk`, you might want to consider using it if you prefer its syntax. It can be more or less cluttered than its counterparts depending on what you need to do.

See [introductory](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/introduction-to-perl-one-liners) [articles](https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/the-top-10-tricks-of-perl-one-liners) to `perl -e`, experiment with  [PCRE](https://regex101.com) or read a useful [`sed`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) or [`awk`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) tutorial.